# Woocommerce product catalog full width and title + price over image (overlay)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, catalog

I'm trying to achieve a full width product catalog with little to no spacing between product images using Woocommerce.
I managed to remove the spacing between product images but the rows aren't full width, leaving me with huge padding on both sides.
Furthermore, how do I get the title and price on top of the image?
I've been messing with css but found no luck.

the final result should look something like this:

acnestudios.com/de/de/man/new-arrivals/

I would really appreciate some help,

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I read, just create or select the class with the price and add what I wrote bellow.

```
.your-class {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 10;
}
```

For the grid I can't help you since you haven't posted anything.
If you're using bootstrap, just use container-fluid instead of container class.

For full grid in WooCommerce add this CSS code:

```
.woocommerce .content-area { width: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important;}
```

I have checked If this code works on Storefront theme -> https://themes.woocommerce.com/storefront/product-category/clothing/

Comment: I am indeed using bootstrap, I haven't figured out how to implement the container-fluid code. can it be done through custom css too?

Comment: I have modified my answer, please accept if this solution worked. Also for container-fluid you just need to add it in php file that is responsible for your products. But If it's WooCommerce default grid, use my code from above.